# sqlalchemy for jython 2.5

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy, jython-2.5

I have installed sqlalchemy package for python 2.7.8 . I want to use the same package in jython 2.5 . I tried inserting the path to the sqlalchemy in the sys.path . however I still always get "No module named sqlalchemy"

Comment: How did you install the package? What's the installed location and what path you added to sys.path?

Comment: I installed using the following command "python setup.py install" . An .egg file was created in C:\python27\lib\site-packages. I added the same path after I launched jython

Comment: Can you try to run the installation script with jython? `jython setup.py install`

Comment: Did that ...do I have to unzip the egg file ?